# Running multiple Btrace scripts

Tags: java, btrace

Do anyone know how to run multiple [btrace](https://btrace.dev.java.net/) scripts at the same time?
I dont want to pre compile and start my program with them. I want plug into the running process with multiple btrace scripts.

Answer (score 2):

VisualVM (can not post a link - just google for it) with installed BTrace plugin (http://kenai.com/projects/btrace/pages/BTracePlugin) supports this.